# How to log Dynamics CRM standard SOAP API calls?

Tags: dynamics-crm

**Context**

We have an on-premise CRM (8.0) application, which is integrated with different legacy systems. There are approx 20 entities which are created/updated/upserted via the standard SOAP API by the legacy systems.

**Question**

I would like to log all the incoming requests and responses as SOAP/XML for diagnostics reasons. How can I accomplish this task?

(Note: I know the trivial, but not exactly fit solution to have workflows for create/update on all affected entities. This seems to be not universal enough + we ultimately must log the request text and response text itself)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it yet, but I think it should be possible to configure the native WCF tracing for the Organization Service. This is something really easy to do (it requires to add some configuration to the web.config file) and you will be able to log any request and response. You can take a look about how to configure it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx).

**EDIT:**
In this link you will be able to see what I've just told you working (it was done for CRM2011 but it should works in newer versions): [link](https://waelhamze.com/2013/02/25/dynamics-crm-2011-organization-service-tracing/)